# parfor and handle classes

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, handle

I have a handle class:

```
classdef A<handle


    properties
        a;
    end

    methods
        function obj = A(a)
            obj.a=a;
        end
    end
end
```

And I have a cell array of `A` objects:

```
arr={};
for i=1:3
    arr{i}=A(i);
end
```

What I would like to do is pass that cell array to a `parfor` loop so that each object's value will change:

```
parfor i=1:3
    arr{i}.a=i*5;
end
```

However, this code does not change `arr` at all. Indeed, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bq__cs7-1.html) it states that

> Changes made to handle classes on the workers during loop iterations are not automatically propagated to the client.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interesting question; I actually never encountered this problem. It's always good to know everything about `parfor` limitations, so I did some googlin' and came up with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26604):

> I have received an answer to this issue from technical support.
>   Apparently the Mathworks regard it as a 'feature' that changes to
>   objects are not returned - though I can't see that it's a very useful
>   feature. Anyway, the way to get modified class properties returned
>   from a parfor loop is to make an explicit change which can be
>   recognised by parfor. Here are two examples which work for the above
>   example object:
>
> ```
> parfor n = 1:num
>     exArray(n).data = n:n+5;
> end
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> parfor n = 1:num
>     temp = exArray(n);
>     setData(temp,n:n+5);
>     exArray(n) = temp;
> end
> ```
>
> Actually, if you change any object property it also seems to work. So
>   for example this also works, if there is a second property data2 which
>   is set explicitly, both data and data2 are correctly returned:
>
> ```
>   parfor n = 1:num
>       setData(exArray(n),n:n+5);
>       exArray(n).data2 = n:n+5;
>   end
> ```

Where the example object is given by

```
classdef Example < handle

    properties
        data
    end

    methods
        function obj = Example(data)
            obj.data = data;
        end

        function setData(obj,data)
            obj.data = data;
        end

        function data = getData(obj)
            data = obj.data;
        end
    end
end
```

and the array is initialized simply as

```
% Initialise array of objects
for n = 1:num
    exArray(n) = Example(zeros(1,6));
end
```

Comment: Actually, it seems it still doesn't work, if I do 
`parfor n = 1:num
    exArray(n).data = n:n+5;
end`
It still does not update `data` outside of the loop

Comment: @noam and if you explicitly define a temporary and call its method, As in the second example? Did you try that?