# parfor does not propagate changes to handle class

Tags: matlab, oop, nested, handle, parfor

In R2018b, consider the following toy class:

```
classdef MyObj < handle

    properties
        use_parallel = true
        test_value   = NaN
    end

    methods
        function myMethod(obj)

            % Call one of the nested functions below:
            if all([obj.use_parallel])
                parallel();                
                disp('Parallel (inside myMethod):')
                [obj.test_value]
            else
                sequential();
                disp('Sequential (inside myMethod):')
                [obj.test_value]
            end

            % Sequentially assign some values
            function sequential()                
                for ii = 1:numel(obj)
                    obj(ii).test_value = ii; end
            end

            % Assign some values in parallel
            function parallel()
                parfor ii = 1:numel(obj)
                    set_value(obj(ii),labindex());
                    obj_copy(ii) = obj(ii);
                end
                obj = obj_copy;
            end

        end
    end
end

% parfor requires subfunction (and not nested function):
function set_value(obj,index)
    obj.test_value = index;
end
```

Though this question closely resembles [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200236/1085062) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35976395/1085062), their underlying problem was essentially some variant of the limitation outlined in [the documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/objects-and-handles-in-parfor-loops.html):

> You can send handle objects as inputs to the body of a parfor-loop. However, any changes made to handle objects on the workers during loop iterations are not automatically propagated back to the client. That is, changes made inside the loop are not automatically reflected after the loop

However, as far as I can see, the toy class above is compliant with the `parfor` slicing rules as well as these particulars regarding handle classes. In my understanding, it should therefore correctly copy the modified `obj` back to `myMethod's` workspace.

However, running the following:

```
clc

% Assign sequentially
M(3) = MyObj();
[M.use_parallel] = deal(false);
M.myMethod();
disp('Sequential (outside class):')
[M.test_value]

disp(' ')

% Assign in parallel 
N(3) = MyObj();
[N.use_parallel] = deal(true);
N.myMethod();
disp('Parallel (outside class):')
[N.test_value]
```

gives on my `parpool` of 6 workers:

```
Sequential (inside myMethod):
ans =
     1     2     3   % <- OK
Sequential (outside class):
ans =
     1     2     3   % <- OK. Nothing unexpected

Parallel (inside myMethod):
ans =
     1     1     1   % <- OK, apparently, lab 1 did everything
Parallel (outside class):
ans =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   % <- hmmm...changes did not propagate
```

This means the `obj.test_value` gets correctly assigned, and the modified `obj` is indeed correctly copied into `myMethod's` workspace. Yet *somehow*, this modified `obj` is a different entity than the `obj` before modification, because the changes do not propagate higher up the stack...

Changing the `parallel()` function to a subfunction (instead of a nested function) and explicitly passing the `obj` parameter around, does not affect this outcome.

Sooooo...what's going on here?

Comment: I might be wrong, I don't use handle classes all that much, but when you do `obj = obj_copy` inside the class method, you are overwriting the `obj` variable with a new value. At this point you no longer have access to the original object inside the class method. Try `obj(:) = obj_copy`, or create a copy method (that copies over individual members) and do `obj.copy(obj_copy)`. One of those should be able to assign the new values to the existing handle class object.

Comment: @CrisLuengo nope, no dice. I also tried subclassing `matlab.mixin.Copyable` (giving me that copy method) and then doing an explicit copy, but no luck either...Normally you can happily overwrite the `obj` with modified copies and it all magically works, but _this_ is starting to feel like a bug...of course, if I change the class into a value class, it all works. But that's not quite what I'm after

Comment: @CrisLuengo see my answer below. Seems I was wrong about the overwriting bit; apparently, that's limited to constructors. This is kind of awkward, because if that's true, then `parfor` is allowed to copy things but we're not allowed to copy any changes back...

Comment: I meant writing a copy method so that you can do `obj.copy(obj_copy)`, where this `copy` method takes the values of the members of `obj_copy` and sets its own members to those values. This way, you modify the existing object, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I guess that's indeed the only way.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB here to test this. Trying it out in Octave would be pointless... :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reduce the problem to this:

```
classdef MyObj < matlab.mixin.Copyable

    properties
        test_value = NaN
    end

    methods
        function myMethod(obj)
            obj = obj.copy();
            obj.test_value = rand;
            disp('Inside method:')
            obj.test_value
        end
    end
end
```

Removing nested functions, subfunctions and `parfor` from the equation. Running the code (after obvious changes) above results in:

```
Inside method:
ans =
     4.8089e-01   % <- obj re-initialized OK
Outside class:
ans =
     NaN          % <- but this does NOT modify the handle class!
```

That means it's a language "feature" I wasn't aware of! Apparently, methods can *modify* existing objects, but not *redefine* them completely. I'll try digging in the documentation to find out some more about this, but this poses a whole new problem: how to copy the changes made by `parfor` back into the object?

TL;DR:

```
function myMethod(obj)
%   ↓ new object   ↓ old object
    obj       =    obj.copy();
```

Cris was right; though the new and old objects have identical names, they are different things—they [shadow](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/90268-shadowing-built-in-functions) each other. Any changes made to the new `obj` will not modify the old `obj`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me. `m=zeros(2); m=1` causes `m` to be `1`, and no longer a 2x2 array. You overwrite the old `m` with the new value. I don't see why this would be different for a handle class.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well, in a constructor you can do things like `obj(30) = MyObj()`. So I guess I just tripped over that. Indeed, a constructor must _return_ `obj`, so ...

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the whole handle class thing fits very poorly in the MATLAB syntax (or at least they don't fit in my intuitive understanding of what happens to objects), and so I often get confused trying to use them. :)